# QT 5.15: Creating a QPushButton crashes a program

Tags: c++, windows, qt, visual-c++, cmake

Using latest QT 5.15.0, c++20, cmake 3.17, MSVC 16.7.2

I have a simple QWidget: (all necessary includes defined in precompiled header)

widget.h

```cpp
#pragma once
#ifndef _WIDGET_H_209323
#define _WIDGET_H_209323

class TestWidget: public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TestWidget(QWidget* parent = nullptr);

private:
    QVBoxLayout* side_panel_;

private:
    auto init_elements() -> void;
};

#endif
```

widget.cpp:

```cpp
#include "widget.h"

TestWidget::TestWidget(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    init_elements();
}

auto TestWidget::init_elements() -> void {
    auto init_main_panel = [this]() {
        side_panel_ = new QVBoxLayout();
        QPushButton* main_view = new QPushButton("test");

        side_panel_->addWidget(main_view);
    };

    init_main_panel();

    this->setLayout(side_panel_);
}
```

The program compiles fine, but crashes at startup with `Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)` and nothing else.

Changing `QPushButton` to any other widget, for example

```cpp
QLabel* label = new QLabel(this);
label->setText("test");
side_panel_->addWidget(label);
```

works as expected, without any problems.

Actually just adding `widget.h` with `QPushButton` to CMakeLists.txt `add_target`, without including it in any other project files crashes the program at startup.

UPDATE:
Tried loading project into Visual Studio and got more meaningful error:

```
The procedure entry point
?hitButton@QPushButton@@MEBA_NAEBVQPoint@@@Z
could not be located int the dynamic link library
```

UPDATE 2:
Changing QT version to 5.14.2 fixes this issue. Both versions installed as MSVC precompiled 64-bit (MSVC2017 for 5.14 and MSVC2019 for 5.15) from official QT installer.

Comment: Did you try running it in a debugger to figure out why it's crashing?

Comment: @JarMan I tried to place a breakpoint in `widget.cpp` but it's never triggered. Not sure what else I can check in debugger.

Comment: Aren't you able to see the line that it crashed on from the debugger?

Comment: @JarMan no,all I get in debugger console is `Couldn't launch process`

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the debugger. Which debugger are you using?

Comment: @JarMan I'm using Clion + LLDB. Don't think it's a debugger problem because I have the same problem in release mode, but when I change `QPushButton` to any other widget like `QLabel` both debug and release builds work fine.

Comment: @JarMan Tried VS and got a better error, updated main post.

Comment: This looks like a DLL conflict. If you have Qt 5.14 DLLs in your PATH, but you compile with Qt 5.15, then at execution it will try to load the corresponding Qt 5.15 DLLs but if it find Qt 5.14 DLLs first, it will load them instead, and they probably have this function missing. Check your PATH, and maybe try to copy the 5.15 DLLs beside the executable to test.

Comment: @Alexandre you are right, had old QT in my path. Can't believe I missed it, thanks.